# How I can load tileLayer in Leaflet framework using local tiles?

Tags: leaflet

I'm using `file:///C:/path/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` like url of tileLayer but it doesn't work and no error is shown.

```
var layer = new L.tileLayer("file:///C:/OSM/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      minZoom: 1,
      maxZoom: 15
}).addTo(map);
```

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to GSE! Please, can you edit your question adding further details, like the code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

I got it running with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />

    <script src=jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>Buslinien</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {

        var map = new L.Map("map", {
            center: new L.LatLng(51.45,8),
            zoom: 9,
        });

        var TopoLayer = L.tileLayer('file:///D:/Tiles/Topo/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { maxZoom: 16 });    
        map.addLayer(TopoLayer);    
    }
    </script>

 <link href="my.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Not sure why it works this way. I guess the map variable has to be defined first.

Comment: Do you think it's possible on mobile phone browser?

Comment: I have no phone to try with, so you have to test it yourself. It might depend on the operating system too.

Comment: My guess is that you are going to run into issues on a web server if you ever publish this as Javascript access to local file systems like that are prohibited.

Comment: @Kristopher surely not, but it is meant to run totally local.

Comment: Tried it on Android 7.0 mobile and it works. HTML file was referenced as file:///sdcard/maps/LeafletExamples/Example.html. Data files were referenced relative to HTML but I suppose it would work also with absolute path.

Comment: I don´t understand the file and folder structure on this. How am I supposed to name my files and folders?

Answer (score 2):

Try using a path relative to your HTML file:

```
L.tileLayer('/map-tiles/{z}/map_{x}_{y}.png', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; ???',
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I've used relative path and it works but I want to use absolute path.