# Tile names & coordinates relationship

Tags: leaflet, android, orthophoto

I'm aware that this site is intended for cartographers, geographers and GIS professionals. I must admit that I'm absolute beginner in the area of maps, but not in the area of programming (40+). I hope somebody will be kind enough to point me in the right direction.

I have map consisting of a set of 256x256 jpg orthophoto tiles. For each tile, I have WGS84 lat/long coordinates and info that 1 pixel is 0.5 m. First I would like to create local Leaflet map on my PC (concept from http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82936/how-i-can-load-tilelayer-in-leaflet-framework-using-local-tiles) and then also on Android (concept from https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8312/how-can-i-can-open-local-files-in-the-default-android-browser).

How far did I manage to get? I found an online map which uses Leaflet: https://mr.si/topo/. One of the layers on this map (Topo) is using tiles the way I want to:
L.tileLayer("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/topo-slovenia/z{z}/{y}/{x}.png", {
            minZoom: 10,
            maxNativeZoom: 15,
            detectRetina: !0,
            attribution: '© GURS',
            unloadInvisibleTiles: !1
        })

Question for me is, of course, how do I name my folders and tiles to correspond to {y} and {x}?

I obtained one of the tiles from above map at address https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/topo-slovenia/z15/11652/17705.png. From another map I got WGS84 (approximate) coordinates of upper left corner of this tile: 46° 2' 34,28" N, 14° 30' 47,06" E. With the help of proj4.js I converted this from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857 (or at least I hope I did) and got 5125467.235607444, 1633146.5805398274. I don't have the slightest idea how this relates to 11652, 17705.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After three weeks of learning about web maps I finally found answers to all of 
my questions. They will be more in the form of tutorial since this may help some 
other beginner.

First I learned how standard tiling for EPSG:3857 works. It's nicely explained on 
http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/. 
Key thing is zoom factor (z). At zoom level 0 whole world is one 256x256 tile. Coordinate 
origin is at the center of the tile (Greenwich at equator), vertical coordinates 
(y) going up 
to 20037508.342789244 and down to -20037508.342789244, horizontal coordinates (x) 
going left to -20037508.342789244 
and right to 20037508.342789244. At zoom level 1 there are 4 equal tiles (2x2), 
at zoom level 2 there are 16 equal tiles (4x4) and so on. Tiles are numbered from 
upper left corner right and down. Upper left is (0,0), first right is (1,0), first 
down is (0,1) and so on. Generally at zoom level z there are 2<sup>z</sup> rows 
and columns of tiles, 
tile (2<sup>z</sup>/2, 2<sup>z</sup>/2 - 1) has upper left corner at coordinates 
(0,0). Another nice tutorial on map tiling systems: 
http://www.liedman.net/tiled-maps/.

Now I had to figure out tiling system of my tiles. One tile covers 128 x 128 
m area. Since number of tile rows and columns at zoom level z is 2<sup>z</sup>, 
I had to find z for which tiles cover whole Slovenia, which covers roughly 260 x 163 
km. With z=11 I got 2048 rows/columns covering area of 262.144 x 262.144 km.

Now the question was how to handle my tiles, which are based on different 
CRS, namely ellipsoidal transverse Mercator EPSG:3912 (old Slovenian D48, which is local Slovenian Gauß-Krüger projection). 
So my tiles have origin, zoom and projection that differ from EPSG:3857. I found 
Leaflet plugin  
[Proj4Leaflet](http://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/) which "allows you to use all kinds of weird projections in 
Leaflet".

To use the Proj4Leaflet plugin I needed the folowing data:

- EPSG:3912 decription in proj4js format: "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 
    +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5000000 +ellps=bessel 
    +towgs84=682,-203,480,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"  (which I found here: 
    http://epsg.io/3912)
- Map area origin. To calculate it I took a reference tile for which I 
    had original row and column numbers and projected coordinates of upper left 
    corner: refRow, refCol, refX and refY. Coordinates of origin (upper left 
    corner), which has row and column number 0, are then origX = refX - refCol*128 
    and origY = refY - refRow*128, assuming that original tiling division was the 
    same as the new one (which luckily proved to be so). Calculated origin was 
    (368000, 243144).
- Pixel/m resolutions 
  for all zoom levels. Since at higest zoom level 11 on pixel was 0.5m, the rest 
    were calculate by multiplying by 2 and the result was: [1024, 512, 256, 128, 
    64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5]

Creation of the map with my custom CRS and for standard tile naming then 
looked like this:

```
var crs3912 = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:3912',
'+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5000000 
+ellps=bessel +towgs84=682,-203,480,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs',
{
  origin: [368000, 243144],
  resolutions: [1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5],
});

var map = L.map('map',
  crs: crs3912,
});

var myLayer = new L.TileLayer("tiles/{z}/{y}/{x}.jpg",
  tileSize: 256,
  maxZoom: 11,
  minZoom: 11,
  attribution: '&copy <a href="http://www.gu.gov.si/">GURS</a>'
});
map.addLayer(myLayer);

map.setView([46.047711, 14.507136], 11);
```

Tile naming of my tiles is completely different, so I just renamed a few of 
them to standard naming to test the above solution and it worked correctly.

The next question was would it be possible to use my tiles without renaming 
them. Their naming scheme is "tiles/ortofoto5000/{y}/SI{x}{y}.jpg", where x and 
y are tile coordinates in three digit hexadecimal format and y is in reverse order (from bottom up). I found the solution 
to this problem here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826338/leaflet-custom-url-custom-tiles 
and here

http://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-2-layers.html.

Creation of the map now 
looked like this:

```
L.TileLayer.MyCustomLayerClass = L.TileLayer.extend({
  getTileUrl: function(coords) {
    coords.x = ('00' + (coords.x).toString(16)).slice(-3);
    coords.y = ('00' + (2047 - coords.y).toString(16)).slice(-3);
    return L.TileLayer.prototype.getTileUrl.call(this, coords);
  }
});

L.tileLayer.myCustomLayer = function(templateUrl, options) {
  return new L.TileLayer.MyCustomLayerClass(templateUrl, options);
}

var crs3912 = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:3912',
"+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5000000 
+ellps=bessel +towgs84=682,-203,480,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs",
{
  origin: [368000, 243144],
  resolutions: [1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5],
});

var map = L.map('map', {
  crs: crs3912,
});

var myLayer = L.tileLayer.myCustomLayer("tiles/ortofoto5000/{y}/SI{x}{y}.jpg", {
  tileSize: 256,
  maxZoom: 11,
  minZoom: 11,
  attribution: '&copy <a href="http://www.gu.gov.si/">GURS</a>'
});
map.addLayer(myLayer);

map.setView([46.180527, 14.507304], 11);
```

And now the final challenge: would this be possible also with original tiles 
available on the web and for all the zoom levels? Tiling scheme of the original 
tiles on the web is quite complex. I managed to decipher it with the help of 
Telerik Fiddler web debugging tool (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). 
I just went through all the zoom levels and watched web requests.

So here is then the final solution:

```
L.TileLayer.MyCustomLayerClass = L.TileLayer.extend({
  getTileUrl: function(coords) {
    var tileS;
    var tileX;
    var tileY;
    var tileZ;
    var tileName;
    var hexX;
    var hexY;
    var hexXhexY;

    tileS = this._getSubdomain(coords);
    tileX = coords.x;
    tileY = (2048 / Math.pow(2, 11 - coords.z)) - coords.y - 1;
    tileZ = 'S' + '789ABCDEFGHI'.charAt(coords.z);
    switch (Math.ceil(coords.z / 4)) {
    case 3:
      var hexX = ('00' + (tileX.toString(16)).toUpperCase()).slice(-3);
      var hexY = ('00' + (tileY.toString(16)).toUpperCase()).slice(-3);
      var hexXhexY = hexX + hexY;
      var tileName = hexXhexY.substr(0, 2) + '/' + hexXhexY.substr(2, 2) + '/' + tileZ 
+ hexXhexY + '.jpg';
      break;
    case 2:
      var hexX = ('0' + (tileX.toString(16)).toUpperCase()).slice(-2);
      var hexY = ('0' + (tileY.toString(16)).toUpperCase()).slice(-2);
      var hexXhexY = hexX + hexY;
      var tileName = hexXhexY.substr(0, 2) + '/' + tileZ + hexXhexY + '.jpg';
      break;
    default:
      var hexX = (tileX.toString(16)).toUpperCase();
      var hexY = (tileY.toString(16)).toUpperCase();
      var tileName = tileZ + hexX + hexY + '.jpg';
  }
  return 'http://gpcl' + tileS + 
'.geopedia.si/v1/AUTH_d7e1266c-6b4e-4629-91e6-17d4b370846d/gurs.dof.50cm.2011.epsg:3912/' 
+ tileZ + '/' + tileName;
}
});

L.tileLayer.myCustomLayer = function(templateUrl, options)
  return new L.TileLayer.MyCustomLayerClass(templateUrl, options);
}

var crs3912 = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:3912',
'+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9999 +x_0=500000 +y_0=-5000000 
+ellps=bessel +towgs84=682,-203,480,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs',
{
  origin: [368000, 243144],
  resolutions: [1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5],
});

var map = L.map('map', {
  crs: crs3912,
});

var myLayer = L.tileLayer.myCustomLayer("", {
  subdomains: ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09'],
  tileSize: 256,
  maxZoom: 11,
  minZoom: 0,
  attribution: '&copy <a href="http://www.gu.gov.si/">GURS</a>'
});

map.addLayer(myLayer);

map.setView([46.047711, 14.507136], 11);
```

Working example is available at jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/vfefa69x/. Example includes also display of 
tile grid and zoom level and projected coordinates, which are useful for 
debugging purposes.

Tile grid is displyed with the help of the following CSS modification:

```
.leaflet-tile {
  border: solid red 1px;
}
```

Zoom level and projected coordinates are displayed with the help of
[Leaflet.Coordinates](https://github.com/MrMufflon/Leaflet.Coordinates) 
plugin.

I also had to learn how to include those github resources into jsfiddle 
example that do not give the right mime type when referenced. I found the 
solution here

https://blog.radix.cc/using-rawgit-to-serve-files-a2e4acad7f2d.

Finnaly I tried this solution on Android 7.0. I simply copied the examples with the resources to Android folder /sdcard/maps/LeafletExamples and called examples in browser by file:///sdcard/maps/LeafletExamples/ExampleN.html. It worked in Chrome and Firefox.