# Leaflet misinterpreting tiles info from an ESRI hosted Tiled Service

Tags: leaflet, arcgis-online, esri-leaflet, tile-server

I am working on showing my ESRI tiled layer to a simple Leaflet web viewer.

The tiled layer is hosted from ArcGIS Online.

I tested both the ESRI Leaflet plugin and the original Leaflet's `tyleLayer` with Leaflet API.

```
var my_tiled_layer_1 = L.esri.tiledMapLayer({
    url: "{MY_ARCGIS_URL}/MapServer"
})

var my_tiled_layer_2 = L.tileLayer('{MY_ARCGIS_URL}/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}');
```

The initialization of the map worked as intended, and the map tried to add tiles from the correct URL. However when it searched for the {x} and {y} coordinates, something got messed up. Either option gave me a whole bunch of 404 responses. From the Developer Tool, I found the actual tiles it was trying to load did not exist at all. For example Leaflet tried to load

```
MapServer/tile/8/155/226
```

However, the actual Level 8 tiles only range from `MapServer/tile/8/16028/10942` to `MapServer/tile/8/16201/11189`

Is there anything I did wrong?

Comment: What is the projection of the map? What is the bounding box of the data for your tile layer? What's the bounding box of the map's viewport when you try to see it?

Comment: relevant sample: http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/non-mercator-projection.html

Comment: Thanks! I have republished the tile layer service in EPSG:3857 (Spatial Reference:102100). The issue still remains. {X} and {Y} values are just accumulating but not start with 0. The URL to the service is: https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/RylLPiI61AyfENce/arcgis/rest/services/VISCAmap3857/MapServer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working wihout `esri_leaflet` plugin by using `Proj4Leaflet` plugin. Parameters for customizing CRS 3857 were taken from ArcGIS service description at https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/RylLPiI61AyfENce/arcgis/rest/services/VISCAmap3857/MapServer. Description of EPSG:3875 for Proj4js comes from http://epsg.io/3857

```
var customCRS = new L.Proj.CRS('customCRS',
               '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs',                       
               {
                 origin: [-20037700, 30241100],
                 resolutions: [2116.670900008467, 1058.3354500042335, 529.1677250021168, 264.5838625010584, 132.2919312505292, 66.1459656252646, 46.30217593768521, 26.458386250105836, 13.229193125052918],
               });  

var map = L.map('map', {
    crs: customCRS
});

var esriLayer = L.tileLayer("http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/RylLPiI61AyfENce/arcgis/rest/services/VISCAmap3857/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}", {
    tileSize: 256,
    maxZoom: 8,
    minZoom: 0,
    attribution: '&copy VISCA map'
}).addTo(map);


map.setView([-36, 144], 0);
```

Comment: Thanks @TomazicM. I was unable to get your example working. I have a base map from OpenStreetMap, i.e. var OpenStreetMap_Mapnik = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
     maxZoom: 19,
     attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    });  as well as a few other overlays. When the map's "crs" option was modified to customCRS, the basemap and the overlays were missing. It seems the map was messed up with projections. Any idea?

Comment: Can you please get another working example with the OpenStreetMap as the basemap?

Comment: The answer is correct considering how the question is formulated. There are no other layers mentioned there. Regarding your additional explanation of the problem, to my knowledge (I'm GIS beginner, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252777/tile-names-coordinates-relationship) it is not possible to show layers with different CRS in the same map.

Comment: Sure. I am happy to mark it answered. I will open another thread for the basemap issue.