# Convert tile naming from crs3912 to crs3857

Tags: javascript

I adapted [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252777/tile-names-coordinates-relationship) that projects crs3912 map to leaflet(crs 3857 if I'm correct) to node.js app that allows me to load this map into applications like Global Mapper, OruxMaps or such. However, zoom and map placement is off place.

I found that the tile https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/15/17795/11679.png geographically corresponds to this geopedia [tile](http://gpcl2.geopedia.si/v1/AUTH_2bbce8a2-a5a9-4d95-9ef7-8643333bc20d/globalvision_quo-tk_2007/SF/A7/SFA75D.jpg), which when converted to decimal would be

> 8/167/162 (z/x/y).

This map goes only till the zoom level 9 where the jpg files are already pixelated, so last usable level is 8.

My question is, simplified, when z/x/y coordinates requested from navigation app are for example 15/17795/11679 how do i get this [tile](http://gpcl2.geopedia.si/v1/AUTH_2bbce8a2-a5a9-4d95-9ef7-8643333bc20d/globalvision_quo-tk_2007/SF/A7/SFA75D.jpg), how to adapt coordinate system and zoom for this to usable in mentioned applications.

Comment: Your assumption about CRS being converted from EPSG 3912 to EPSG 3857 in Leaflet is not correct. Leaflet uses proj4.js library to correctly display map that is in EPSG 3912. There is no conversion being done. Which library/package are you using to display map? Are you trying to display OSM map? And by the way, example you are refering to is using totaly exotic tile system that has nothing to do with usual z/x/y system.

Comment: I wrote a proxy web app that simply converts z/x/y to hex, then when i load this as a link into global mapper as online map, something like mywebapp.me/z/x/y it shows me whole map. I'm trying to use global mapper or oruxmaps on mobile to show me this map and I can see it and zoom through levels. Hope it makes sense. Beginner here in regard to maps btw.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to display Geopedia map of Slovenia. Tiles in example are actually PZS variant of Geopedia. And you are right, maximum zoom level is 9 and maximum zoom level without pixelation is 8. If you want higher zooms, your app has to take care of that by zooming/enlarging tiles from zoom level 9. In my case Leaflet is doing that.