# How does Leaflet know the spatial information of PNG files when adding tileLayers

Tags: leaflet, tiles, tilemill, mbutil

I am learning web mapping. I created tiles with TileMill, exported them to `.mbtiles`, and used MBUtil to unpack them. This gives me a hierarchy of folders of png files. I then added the tiles to Leaflet map using `L.tileLayer('<path to top folder>/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map)`. This works. I found there was a `metadata.josn` file at the top folder, which contains information on bounds and so on. I removed the json file, and the tile layer still works perfectly. This surprised me. Where does Leaflet get the spatial information from PNG files to decide which images to show?

Comment: What is the map area covered by tiles? Try to put a marker with known lat,long coordinates on the map. Does it show in the right place? See answer to this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354329/using-gdal2tiles-xml-output-with-proj4leaflet/354386#354386

Comment: Thx for pointing to the post. It did help. So I guess it's because the way the folders are structured contains location information.

Comment: Yes, folder structure + coordinates of upper left corner of map area + (resolution or map area bounds).

Comment: I think in this case the map area wasn't provided with the files. Or maybe it did, but even after I removed it (the json file), the map still seems to work. I think it may be because Leaflet and the data both follow the map area and zoom level conventions used by Google Maps and Open Street Map.

Comment: Did you try to put a marker with known lat,long coordinates on the map. Was it shown at the right place?